# Quixel to Blender how to chage tile repeat on all texture maps at once?

Tags: texturing

Looking for a function like Marmoset Toolbag uses where the repeat value changes for all maps at the same time.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: the links are to the screenshot images showing the node networks. Also, Looks like someone understood the question enough to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size by changing the scale values in this node tree:

[image]

Comment: Quixel Shader Graph
https://i.postimg.cc/vHCVvbdC/Blender-Quixel-Shader-Graph.jpg

Comment: Sometimes Quixel imports double nodes. 2 of albedo, 2 of normal 2 bump etc. not sure yet why that is.

Comment: Here is one way to tile all texture maps: https://i.postimg.cc/L5Hr7cFp/Blender-Quixel-FIXED-Shader-Graph.jpg